# How do I tell if a variable in xslt is greater than another

Tags: xslt

Each of these variables has an integer value.  But this syntax is not valid for some reason:

```
<xsl:when test="$nextAnswerListItemPos < $nextQuestionStemPos" >
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You have to use `&lt;` instead of `<` and `&gt;` instead of `>`, because those are reserved characters.

Answer (score 10):

Also, in XSLT 2.0, you can use the operators "gt" (greater than), "lt" (less than), and "eq" (equal).  Using these instead of the entities makes your code a bit cleaner.

Comment: Please note that .net only supports XSLT 1.0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525299/xpath-and-xslt-2-0-for-net you need saxon for 2.0