# XPath 2.0 Libraries for .Net

Tags: .net, xpath, xpath-2.0

Which [XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) libraries (apart from [saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/)) are available, preferably for .Net?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a recently announced new XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: @Abel I disagree, the other question is about XPath support in the .Net framework, I'm looking for 3rd party libraries.

Comment: I see and understand now, I'll remove that comment. Update: see related discussion on support in .NET Framework: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525299/xpath-and-xslt-2-0-for-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** see Dimitre's answer for [XQSharp Beta, now renamed XMLPrime](https://www.xmlprime.com/xmlprime/index.htm), which contains an XSLT/XPath 2.0 processor.

Unfortunately, the answer is disappointing: none whatsoever. Microsoft [did have plans and even asked the community for input](https://web.archive.org/web/20140410181634/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2005/06/07/426511.aspx), but never materialized them. There was a moment [where they seemed to investigate whether it was feasible](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/77d7d224-0677-4c58-86df-fbc4f20f675b/whenif-xslt-20-will-be-supported-in-net?forum=xmlandnetfx), but no plans have been announced up until .NET 4.5. See also [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525299/xpath-and-xslt-2-0-for-net), which answers this in more detail. M. David Peterson [has a blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20090621155522/http://oreillynet.com:80/xml/blog/2007/10/its_october_2007_do_you_know_w.html) that tracks a bit of the efforts of Microsoft till end 2007.

Also, there's [this thread by me on the xsl-list](https://markmail.org/search/?q=Definite%20list%20of%20XSLT%202.0%20processors?#query:Definite%20list%20of%20XSLT%202.0%20processors?%20from:%22Michael%20Kay%22%20page:1%20mid:pzdd5iv7o22jyw7l%20state:results), which shows some efforts of other companies so far, but nothing on the .NET front. See the answer by Michael Kay.

Comment: I know this answer is a little old, however, there is some link rot going on here.

Comment: @javamonkey79 thanks for the pointer, I've updated the links (and the text).

Answer (score 3):

**See the recently announced (Sep. 2010) [XQSharp XSLT 2.0 processor](http://www.xqsharp.com/xqsharp/beta.htm)**.

It is developed in and for .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Lightweight XPath2 for .NET seems promising.