# XPath matches() using regular expressions in C#

Tags: c#, regex, xpath

**Update:** I wrote up what I did, with source code and things to watch for, at - [Adding XPath 2.0 functionality and variables to .NET XPath](http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2011/07/adding-xpath-20-functionality-and-variables-to-net-xpath.html) (my blog).

Is there a way to pass a regular expression to matches() for an XPath statement in .NET?

Example: do an xpath of

```
"/windward-studios/Employees/Employee[matches(string(LastName), '.*A?B[12]C.*')]"
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Interesting.  Haven't had to use this xpath functionality so I didn't know it wasn't supported in .NET until seeing the answers.  Looks like this other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525299/xpath-and-xslt-2-0-for-net covers libraries that provide support in .NET .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XPath 2.0 supports the matches function.  However, .Net implements XPath 1.0.

You would need to add a custom function to implement match.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950806.aspx

It looks like the Mvp.Xml Project: EXSLT.NET module implements most of XPath 2.0; including matches.  See http://mvp-xml.sourceforge.net/exslt/

Comment: what about net core?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's XSLT processor does not support XSLT 2.0, but there are at least two others available on .NET that do: Saxon and XQSharp.

Microsoft basically decided some time ago to go down a proprietary route with Linq, and if you want to stick with a standards-based approach, you will have to go to third parties.