# Regex, start with capital letters in Xpath

Tags: c#, xml, regex

Trying to get all the words in text nodes which start with a capital letter, trying

`SelectNodes("//*[contains(text(), [A-Z])]");` but wont compile, I'm new to regex and i really can't find anything, looked everywhere.

Comment: XPath does not support regular expressions. I'm not sure that what you're trying to do is possible.

Comment: does xpath 2.0 not now support some stuff? im new to this but read something about that

Comment: I see. I have an answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SelectNodes("//*[matches(text(), '^[A-Z]')]");
```

However, you may need to [follow these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6447689/13) before it will work.

Comment: thanks, it is says "Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function." now though, what have i failed this time?

Comment: A quick Google turned this up: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13511527/13. It sounds like your XML has some namespaces that has to be added to the namespace manager.

Comment: I'm getting the error "XsltContext is needed for this query because of an unknown function." the common answer is people using.net and not having xpath 2 it seems, im using visual studio 11, would this have xpath 2? is this the issue?

Comment: Oh dear, that's because .NET doesn't actually support XPath 2.0 out of the box: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6447476/13 (see the top answer for a workaround).

Comment: .NET is the name of the platform that C# programs run on. :-D

Comment: weird that i was asked to do this for a job interview then (they know ive never programmed in c# before)

Comment: I guess they were trying to tell how "never" you've done C#. :-P

Comment: The solution given using matches() is correct for XPath 2.0. However, .NET does not support XPath 2.0 "out of the box" - you need to install something like Saxon or XmlPrime.