# What version of XPath does XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode use?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I'm using the `XmlDocument` class like this:

```
divisionsDoc.SelectSingleNode(
    string.Format(@"Root/PoliticalDivisions/PoliticalDivision[upper-case(@Code)='{0}']", withCode.ToUpper()));
```

And this is resulting in the error:

> Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix,
>   variable, or user-defined function.

I gather this is due to the `upper-case` XPath function, which I understand exists in XPath 2.0 and not 1.0 (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893551/case-insensitive-matching-in-xpath), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625446/problem-with-upper-case-and-lower-case-xpath-functions-in-selenium-ide), etc.)

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectsinglenode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't specify the version of XPath it uses.  I'm targeting .NET 4.5.1 -- wouldn't that be late enough to be using XPath 2.0?  Or is that something that is defined elsewhere (outside of .NET)?

**How can I find out what version of XPath is being targeted?**

Please note, I'm aware of the work-around using `translate('some text','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')` -- that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: As an aside, do you *need* to use XPath here? I'd personally just use LINQ to XML - no need to worry about whether `withCode` contains apostrophes, for example - but I appreciate you may have other requirements.

Comment: [Basic Querys Linq to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx)

Comment: No... Microsoft never implemented XPath 2.0 or Xslt 2.0. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/7521282/613130 of 2011. In one comment someone asked for an update in 2014...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Microsoft never implemented XPath 2.0 or Xslt 2.0... See for example this [uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3795831-native-support-for-xpath-2-0-or-xslt-2-0-in-net) (aptly named *Native support for XPath 2.0 or XSLT 2.0 in .NET*) of 2013...

Last comment of March 2015 by one user:

> i guess we will never see this as the world doesn't like XML anymore, it's all about JSON. Which is a shame as XML is still far better for a number of key scenarios than JSON.

Comment: This is incredibly disheartening that in 2018 XPath 1.0 is still the only supported version in .NET

Comment: Yeah and if you try that link now, you'll see that they've completely taken the User Voice down. There is no "User Voice".