# Xpath count and compare datetime

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, xpath, count

Below is my xml...

What I am trying to do is using XPATH and count expression.. I want a count of when a date in xml matches Todays date. So for example Todays Date is "2011-05-05".. Any messages that match this date have a count and return a integer. so answer would be NumberofTodaysMessages = 2.

```
<Response>
    <run_id>1</run_id>
    <message>
      <timestamp>2011-05-05T10:50:00.46875+00:00</timestamp>
      <event_type>Information</event_type>
      <operation>LoadProjects</operation>
      <error_code />
      <details>LoadProjects request detected</details>
    </message>
    <message>
      <timestamp>2011-05-05T10:50:02.296875+00:00</timestamp>
      <event_type>Error</event_type>
      <operation>Processor.InitaliseDCFiles</operation>
      <error_code />
      <details>some error details</details>
    </message>
    <message>
      <timestamp>2011-11-10T10:50:02.296875+00:00</timestamp>
      <event_type>Debug</event_type>
      <operation>Processor.InitaliseDCFiles</operation>
      <error_code />
      <details>some details</details>
    </message>
  <Response>
```

How would I go about this in XPATH??

**count(/Response/message/Timestamp[@DateTime.Now()])**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# implements XPath 2.0, right? Then you should have all these [functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#comp.duration.datetime) available.

Comment: There is no XPath 2.0 implementation in .Net framework up to at least 4.0. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525299/xpath-and-xslt-2-0-for-net if you need one.

Comment: OK, maybe I was misled by this statement: "The System.Xml.XPath namespace contains the classes that define a cursor model for navigating and editing XML information items as instances of the XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Data Model." of the MSDN library.

Comment: Framework 4.5 supports XPath 2.0 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath?view=netframework-4.5

Answer (score 1):

the xpath could be:

today = "2011-11-05" // replace by "today" in a string with your date library

xpath = "Response/message/timestamp[starts-with(text()='"+today+"')]"

Comment: Could not do..... xpath = "Response/message/timestamp[starts-with(text()='"+DATETIME.NOW()+"')]" ?? Because I want to run this everyday..

Comment: build your xpath syntax using the string 'today' so you end with something like this:
"Response/message/timestamp[starts-with(text()='2011-11-05')]"

Comment: so.... today = DATETIME.NOW().ToString()  xpath = "Response/message/timestamp[starts-with(text()='"+today+"')]"