# Get xml node with last date

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

I have next xml:

```
<Histories>
    <History>
        <Date>20.06.2010</Date>
        <FileName>4.txt</FileName>
    </History>
    <History>
        <Date>05.06.2012</Date>
        <FileName>2.txt</FileName>
    </History>
    <History>
        <Date>18.12.1999</Date>
        <FileName>3.txt</FileName>
    </History>
</Histories>
```

I need to get last node by date (set XPath witch return date). How can I do? Example: 2.txt

Thanks

Comment: >/Histories/History[
  not(
    (preceding-sibling::History | following-sibling::History)/Date > Date
  )
] not work for my formate date

Comment: Indeed. It is not possible to do this with your date-format in just XPath 1.0. Alternatives offered are: XPath 2.0, LINQ to XML, XSLT and XQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had proper dates in your XML (`yyyyddmm` instead of `dd.mm.yyyy`), this XPath 1.0 would work:

```
/Histories/History[
  not(
    (preceding-sibling::History | following-sibling::History)/Date > Date
  )
]
```

Since you have your dates the wrong way, XPath 1.0 cannot do this.

Answer (score 3):

In XPath 2.0 you can do it like this:

```
/Histories/History[
    concat(substring(Date,7),substring(Date,4,2),substring(Date,1,2)) =
    max(/Histories/History/concat(substring(Date,7),substring(Date,4,2),
        substring(Date,1,2)))
]
```

The first part (`concat(...)`) converts the date into `YYYYMMDD` format to allow sorting. It then compares it to the maximum such value in the file.

This would not be possible in XPath 1.x, since there are no `max()` function, nor can you call functions at the end of a path (`/Histories/History/concat(...)`).

Natively, .NET does not support XPath 2.0, but [there are libraries that add this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525299/xpath-and-xslt-2-0-for-net).

Comment: +1. If the OP had useful date formats, this would be pretty simple in XPath 1.0. I've added an "if only"-solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is not specific to WPF.

Did you try using `XQuery` or `XLinq` for this?

```
        var element = XElement.Parse(<yourXml>);
        var lastDateHistoryNode
              = element.XPathSelectElements("//History").OrderByDescending(
                   e => DateTime.ParseExact(
                          e.Element("Date").Value, "dd.MM.yyyy", null)).First();
        var lastDateFileName = lastDateHistoryNode.Element("FileName").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath on its own won't allow you to select from an ordered list.  If you can use XSLT first (in particular `<xsl:sort>`) to obtain a sorted node-set, then selecting the first or last element is trivial (`nodeset[1]` or `nodeset[last()]`.

To have the dates sorted chronologically it's also wise to convert them to ISO first (`YYYY-MM-DD`) as then the string order coincides with the chronological order.

Comment: XPath does not let you select from an ordered list, but there are ways to get the minimum/maximum value from a node set - as long as the values sort naturally (which `dd.mm.yyyy` does not do, unfortunately).