# excel xml to xml - xslt for iterating inner loop

Tags: xml, excel, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am struggling to convert an excel xml file to another xml format.

Here is a simplified extract of the source:

```
<Workbook>
  <Worksheet>
    <Table>
      <Row>
        <Cell>
          <Data>Test 1</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data>Preconditions for test 1</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data>The setup for test 1</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell />
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell />
        <Cell>
          <Data>Step 1</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data>Todo in step 1</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data>Expected result</Data>  <!--omitted if empty-->
        </Cell>
      </Row>
         .
         .
      <Row>
        <Cell />
        <Cell>
          <Data>Step n</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data>Todo in step n</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data>Expected result</Data>  <!--omitted if empty-->
        </Cell>
      </Row>
         .
         .
 -----------------
         .
         .
      <Row>
        <Cell>
          <Data>Test m</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data>Preconditions for test m</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data>The setup for test m</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell />
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell />
        <Cell>
          <Data>Step 1</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data>Todo in step 1</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell />
        <Cell>
          <Data>Expected result</Data>  <!--omitted if empty-->
        </Cell>
      </Row>          
         .
         .
      <Row>
        <Cell />
        <Cell>
          <Data>Step k</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data>Todo in step k</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data>Expected result</Data> <!--omitted if empty-->
        </Cell>
      </Row>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Column 2 (Cell[2]) can be seen as header for cols 3-4

My desired output should be in the following format:

```
<case>
  <title>Test 1</title>
  <precond>The setup for test 1</precond>
  <step>
    <index>1</index>
    <content>Todo in step 1</content>
    <expected>Expected result</expected> <!--omitted if empty-->
  </step>
     .
     .
  <step>
    <index>n</index>
    <content>Todo in step n</content>
    <expected>Expected result</expected> <!--omitted if empty-->
  </step>
</case>
   .
   .
.......
   .
   .
<case>
  <title>Test m</title>
  <precond>The setup for test m</precond>
  <step>
    <index>1</index>
    <content>Todo in step 1</content>
    <expected>Expected result</expected>  <!--omitted if empty-->
  </step>
    .
    .
  <step>
    <index>n</index>
    <content>Todo in step n</content>
    <expected>Expected result</expected>  <!--omitted if empty-->
  </step>
</case>
```

My problem is to define the xslt so that the `<case>` tags encompass all the rows up until the next row which has a data entry in Cell[1]. If I use `<xsl:if test="Cell[1]/Data">` to find the next *test*, the closing `</case>` must be entered before `</xsl:if>` and thus I need to iterate the following sibling rows (test steps) within that statement. How do I accomplish that?

Here's my feeble attempt at an xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />


<xsl:template match="Workbook/Worksheet/Table">
  <xsl:for-each select="Row">
    <xsl:if test="Cell[1]/Data">   
      <case>
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="Cell[1]/Data"/>
        </title>
        <xsl:if test="Cell[3]/Data">
          <precond>
            <xsl:value-of select="Cell[3]/Data"/>
          </precond>
        </xsl:if>

        <!-- Here I need to iterate "while not" following-sibling::Cell[1]/Data and extract the data from cells 2-4.-->

      </case>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Does it need to be XSLT 1.0 or do you have the ability to use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Mark, I haven't really considered the differences. I am not well acquainted with either. I have made a little C# program using System.Xml.Xsl as an engine in .net. From [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525299/xpath-and-xslt-2-0-for-net) it seems that xslt 1.0 is necessary

Comment: Also added a XSLT 1.0 solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are stuck with XSLT 1.0, Indexing is a possible and easy way:

```
<xsl:key name="steps" match="Row[not(Cell[1]/Data)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Row[Cell[1]/Data][1])"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <result>
    <xsl:for-each select="//Row[Cell[1]/Data]">
      <case>
        <title><xsl:value-of select="Cell[1]/Data"/></title>
        <precond><xsl:value-of select="Cell[3]/Data"/></precond>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('steps', generate-id(.))">
          <step>
            <index><xsl:value-of select="Cell[2]/Data" /></index>
            <content><xsl:value-of select="Cell[3]/Data" /></content>
            <expected><xsl:value-of select="Cell[4]/Data" /></expected>
          </step>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </case>
    </xsl:for-each>     
  </result>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you. Both this and Mark's solutions work. Not caring about efficiency, I pick this solution for code size.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use XSLT 2.0, you could use the following XSLT as an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity template to 'loop' through all input XML (nodes and attributes) -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- create new root element -->
    <xsl:template match="Workbook">
        <data>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </data>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Match on Table element, to do some grouping -->
    <xsl:template match="Table">
        <!-- Group all rows together, each group starts with a Row where Cell[1] is not empty -->
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Row" group-starting-with="Row[Cell[1] != '']">
            <case>
                <title><xsl:value-of select="Cell[1]/Data" /></title>
                <precond><xsl:value-of select="Cell[3]/Data" /></precond>
                <!-- Loop through the group, but forget the first occurence, since it is the header, use before this -->
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()[position() &gt; 1]">
                    <step>
                        <index><xsl:value-of select="Cell[2]/Data" /></index>
                        <content><xsl:value-of select="Cell[3]/Data" /></content>
                        <expected><xsl:value-of select="Cell[4]/Data" /></expected>
                    </step>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </case>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The following XSLT will work in XSLT 1.0 and even in XSLT 2.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity template to 'loop' through all input XML (nodes and attributes) -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- create new root element -->
    <xsl:template match="Workbook">
        <data>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::Row[Cell[1] != '']" />
        </data>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Match Rows where first Cell is empty and create the <case> element with header information -->
    <xsl:template match="Row[Cell[1] != '']">
        <case>
            <title><xsl:value-of select="Cell[1]/Data" /></title>
            <precond><xsl:value-of select="Cell[3]/Data" /></precond>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count(following-sibling::Row[Cell[1] != '']) = 0">
                    <!-- When there are no next Row elements with empty first Cells, we can just process the remaining Rows -->
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Row[Cell[1] = '']" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <!-- There are still Rows with empty first Cells, so we only process the Rows in between -->
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Row[Cell[1] != ''][1]/preceding-sibling::Row[Cell[1] = '']" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </case>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Process Rows with empty first Cells, which will be the step information -->
    <xsl:template match="Row[Cell[1] = '']">
        <step>
            <index><xsl:value-of select="Cell[2]/Data" /></index>
            <content><xsl:value-of select="Cell[3]/Data" /></content>
            <expected><xsl:value-of select="Cell[4]/Data" /></expected>
        </step>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```