# How to write xapth For each loop for tr and td tags in c#.net

Tags: c#, xpath

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td id="a">
           Battery
      <td id ="b">
          9
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td id="a">
           Company
       <td id="b">
              APPLE
  </tr>
  <tr>....</tr>
```

I  need the output like this battery:9^Comapany:Apple.  I am learning xpath can any one suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using XPath 2.0 you can do the following:

```
fn:string-join(for $tr in //tr return fn:string-join($tr/td/text(),':'), '^')
```

**Updated after your comment:**
.NET Framework does not directly support XPath 2.0 and I don't believe your requirements can be easily satisfied using 1.0. You may have a look at some [third-party librarie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525299/xpath-and-xslt-2-0-for-net)s.

Alternatively, if you're just looking for a C# solution, there's no need to use XPath here, LINQ to XML would be sufficient:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(myXmlString);
var result =
   String.Join("^",
               xDoc.Descendants("tr")
                   .Select(tr => String.Join(":",
                                             tr.Elements("td")
                                               .Select(td => td.Value.Trim()))));
```

Finally - it should be noted that both of those methods will only work on properly formed Xml - yours is not (no ending tags for `td` elements). If you want to work on Html, as your sample seems to suggest, you may want to use a tool that is designed to work with it, e.g. [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).