# XSLT in SharePoint

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, server-side

As far as I know, SharePoint 2013 only supports XSLT 1.0.
What will be the destiny of XSLT in SharePoint 2016? IS it possible to deprecate XSLT? If the answer is yes, what is the alternative solution for server-side rendering?

Comment: Is it possible to deprecate XSLT in SharePoint?

Comment: StackOverflow is for answering programming questions, not for fortune-tellers.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that XSLT 2.0 will be supported - MS seems to have taken the position that there's not enough demand to make it worthwhile to natively support XSLT 2.0 in the .NET framework; they seem more invested in building up LINQ to XML instead.  As to whether XSLT will be deprecated, that would be surprising but who could say?

Comment: Thank you Dan, Is there any other solution for server-side rendering in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Michael Kay that we shouldn't try to predict the future here, but if we rephrase your question to how you can use XSLT 2.0 with SharePoint, I think the question is valid enough ;).

That said, there apparently have been third parties that make XSLT 2.0 available from SharePoint. How that works exactly, I do not know, but [this tool or toolset seems to offer you the possibility of XSLT 2.0 in Sharepoint](http://appdevonsharepoint.com/adding-xslt-2-0-intellisense-to-visual-studio/) and comes with a handy suggestion to update Visual Studio to make development easier.

Whether or not you can, or want to use [Corasworks](http://appdevonsharepoint.com/) to get XSLT 2.0 working is a judgement I cannot make, of course. If you can somehow just use a native .NET XSLT 2.0 (or 3.0) processor, as far as I know, you can choose from [XmlPrime](http://xmlprime.com), [Saxonica](http://saxonica.com) and [Exselt](http://exselt.net) (disclaimer, I wrote the latter, and it is still in development).

> Side note: Microsoft [first claimed it would support XSLT 2.0 at some point](http://my-tech-talk.blogspot.nl/2009/08/where-is-microsofts-xslt-2.html), but stated later that it would not do so in the near future, and [yet later that it would probably never do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525299/xpath-and-xslt-2-0-for-net) and leave it to others to implement XSLT 2.0 in .NET. This logically leads to the [same response on SharePoint and XSLT 2.0](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73718/how-to-use-xslt-2-0-in-sharepoint), but they are somewhere on the internet.