# Removing nodes from a large XML file using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, io

I'm in a situation where I need to take an XML file and remove a bunch of unnecessary nodes but because the file I've been supplied with is around 1.6GB so it's not really feasible to use something like `XmlDocument.Load` as it'd be very resource heavy.

Given this, I have been trying to solve my issue using both `$reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($path)` and `$writer = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create("C:\test\123.xml")`

In order to try and remove unnecessary items I tried the following:

```
# Set the path to your XML file
$path = "C:\test\test.xml"

# Create an XmlReader object to read the file
$reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($path)

# Create an XmlWriter object to write the modified XML
$writer = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create("C:\test\123.xml")

# Create a namespace manager and add the namespace prefix and URI
$nsManager = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($reader.NameTable)
$nsManager.AddNamespace("g", "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0")

# Loop through the XML and remove unwanted nodes
while ($reader.Read()) {
    if ($reader.NodeType -eq "Element") {
      if ($reader.LocalName -eq "Item") {
         # Enter the Item element and loop through its child nodes
            $itemDepth = $reader.Depth
            while ($reader.Read() -and $reader.Depth -gt $itemDepth) {
                Write-Output $reader.LocalName
                # Remove unwanted child nodes of Item element
                if ($reader.NodeType -eq "Element" -and $reader.LocalName -eq "description") {
                    Write-Output Skip
                    $reader.Skip()
                } else {
                    # Write the node to the output file
                    $writer.WriteNode($reader, $false)
                }
            }
      } else{
        $writer.WriteNode($reader, $false)
      }
    }
}

# Clean up
$reader.Close()
$writer.Close()
```

This approach was maybe 50% of the way there, but the issue I have is that when the parent node is written, it also writes all the children. The inner logic does work but if I remove the outer `else` it does not create the root of the document so I get an error about invalid XML.

As you'll see below it essentially gets to `<channel>` and copies everything in between.

For reference I have included a scaled down version of the XML file I've been using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:c="http://base.google.com/cns/1.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Title</title>
        <link>https://site.test</link>
        <description date="2023-03-07 12:15:08">Some description of my feed.</description>
        <item>
            <g:id>1234-5678-9876</g:id>
            <title>Title</title>
            <description>Description</description>
            <link></link>
            <g:price>146.00 GBP</g:price>
            <g:sale_price>48.70 GBP</g:sale_price>
            <g:google_product_category>Clothing</g:google_product_category>
            <g:product_type>Clothing</g:product_type>
            <g:brand>Jayley</g:brand>
            <g:condition>new</g:condition>
            <g:age_group>Adult</g:age_group>
            <g:color>Lilac</g:color>
            <g:gender>Female</g:gender>
            <g:pattern>Striped</g:pattern>
            <g:size>One Size</g:size>
            <g:item_group_id>5f5a22dbb7c91</g:item_group_id>
            <g:custom_label_0>Womens</g:custom_label_0>
            <g:shipping>
                <g:country>GB</g:country>
                <g:service>Standard Delivery</g:service>
                <g:price>1.99 GBP</g:price>
            </g:shipping>
            <c:count type="string">1</c:count>
        </item>
        <item>
            ...
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Also, for reference, if I remove the outer else you can see it does loop through the children but then the XML is invalid.

[image]

Comment: So, based on your example you just want `<description>Description</description>` be removed and everything else should be copied as-is?

Comment: Yes, I literally just want to prune some redundant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$writer.WriteNode($reader, $false)` processes the current element of the reader **recursively**. It advances the reader position past the current element.

So `WriteNode()` is useless to write XML nodes that should not be completely copied from the input to the output XML. Instead, use the more specific `XmlWriter` methods `WriteStartElement`, `WriteStartAttribute`, `WriteString` and `WriteEndAttribute` to build output elements piece-wise.

This example removes `Description` elements that are children of `Item`.

```bash
$inputPath  = 'input.xml'
$outputPath = 'output.xml'

# Create absolute, native paths for .NET API (which doesn't respect PowerShell's current directory)
$fullInputPath = Convert-Path -LiteralPath $inputPath
$fullOutputPath = (New-Item $outputPath -ItemType File -Force).FullName

$reader = $writer = $null

# Hashtable that stores the path segments that lead to the current element
$elementPath = @{}

try {
    # Create an XmlReader for the input file
    $reader = [Xml.XmlReader]::Create( $fullInputPath )

    # Create an XmlWriter for the output file
    $writer = [Xml.XmlWriter]::Create( $fullOutputPath )

    # Read first node (XML declaration)
    $null = $reader.Read()

    while( -not $reader.EOF ) {

        if( $reader.NodeType -eq [Xml.XmlNodeType]::Element ) {

            # Keep track of where we are in the element tree
            $elementPath[ $reader.Depth ] = $reader.Name

            # If current element is 'Description' and its parent is 'Item', skip it
            if( $reader.Name -eq 'Description' -and $elementPath[ $reader.Depth - 1 ] -eq 'Item' ) {
                # Skip current element
                $reader.Skip()

                # Skip any whitespace after element to avoid empty line in output
                while( -not $reader.EOF -and $reader.NodeType -eq [Xml.XmlNodeType]::Whitespace ) {
                    $reader.Skip()
                }   

                continue
            }

            # Write the start tag of current element
            $writer.WriteStartElement( $reader.Prefix, $reader.LocalName, $reader.NamespaceUri )
            
            if( $reader.HasAttributes ) {
                # Write the attributes of current element
                while( $reader.MoveToNextAttribute() ) {
                    $writer.WriteStartAttribute( $reader.Prefix, $reader.LocalName, $reader.NamespaceUri )
                    $writer.WriteString( $reader.Value )
                    $writer.WriteEndAttribute()
                }                
            }

            # Read next node
            $null = $reader.Read()
        }
        else {
            # If NodeType is EndElement, it writes the end tag.
            # Otherwise it copies any non-element node. 
            # Advances reader position as well!
            $writer.WriteNode( $reader, $false )
        }
    }    
}
finally {
    # Cleanup
    $reader, $writer | ForEach-Object Dispose
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, it didn't occur to me that you can build out the top and bottom and just filter the middle. Using your example I made a version that exactly fits my needs. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I can't help with the technology you're using, but you could do it with a streaming XSLT 3.0 transformation like this:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0"
               xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:template match="item/description"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Nice, but AFAIK .NET (and PowerShell) only support XSLT 1.0 out-of-the-box. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1533114/7571258) lists two external libraries that support XSLT 3.0.

Comment: Microsoft are 20 years behind the curve with their XML technology. If you're doing anything serious with XML on Microsoft platforms, you need to think out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer provided by @zett42 I made a version that deals with multiple unwanted nodes. Obviously I'm assuming in this example that everything is three levels deep but this could be adjusted.

Anyway, this is what I ended on.

```
$timer = Measure-Command {
    $inputPath  = 'C:\test\test.xml'
    $outputPath = 'C:\test\test99.xml'

    $fullInputPath = Convert-Path -LiteralPath $inputPath
    $fullOutputPath = (New-Item $outputPath -ItemType File -Force).FullName

    $reader = $writer = $null

    try {
        # Create an XmlReader for the input file
        $reader = [Xml.XmlReader]::Create( $fullInputPath )

        # Create an XmlWriter for the output file
        $writer = [Xml.XmlWriter]::Create( $fullOutputPath )

        # Read first node (XML declaration)
        $null = $reader.Read()

        while( -not $reader.EOF ) {

            if( $reader.NodeType -eq [Xml.XmlNodeType]::Element ) {

                # Define an array of node names to skip
                $skipNodes = @(
                    'g:condition',
                    'g:material',
                    'g:age_group',
                    'g:gender',
                    'g:pattern',
                    'g:mpn',
                    'g:shipping',
                    'g:custom_label_0',
                    'g:custom_label_1',
                    'g:custom_label_2',
                    'g:custom_label_3',
                    'g:custom_label_4',
                    'g:custom_label_5',
                    'g:country',
                    'g:service',
                    'g:promotion_id',
                    'g:product_highlight',
                    'c:shopping_spend',
                    'c:fs_data_opti',
                    'c:fs_date_of_birth',
                    'c:fs_data_original_id',
                    'c:fs_data_original_title',
                    'c:sales_feature',
                    'c:stock',
                    'c:google_product_name',
                    'c:count',
                    'c:order_number'
                )

                # Should the current element be removed from the output?
                if ($reader.Depth -eq 3 -and $skipNodes.Contains($reader.Name)) {
                    $reader.Skip()

                    # Read the next line to check if it's blank
                    $nextLine = $reader.ReadOuterXml()

                    # If the next line is blank, replace it with an empty string
                    if ($nextLine -match '^\s*$') {
                        $output = $output -replace "$nextLine", ''
                    }

                    continue
                }

                $writer.WriteStartElement( $reader.Prefix, $reader.LocalName, $reader.NamespaceUri )
                
                if( $reader.HasAttributes ) {
                    # Copy attributes
                    while( $reader.MoveToNextAttribute() ) {
                        $writer.WriteStartAttribute( $reader.Prefix, $reader.LocalName, $reader.NamespaceUri )
                        $writer.WriteString( $reader.Value )
                        $writer.WriteEndAttribute()
                    }                
                }

                # Read next node
                $null = $reader.Read()
            }
            else {
                # Copy any non-element node. Advances reader position as well!
                $writer.WriteNode( $reader, $false )
            }
        }    
    }
    finally {
        # Cleanup
        $reader, $writer | ForEach-Object Dispose
    }
}

"Elapsed time: $($timer.TotalSeconds) seconds"
```

If anyone has any feedback I'm all ears.

For reference this managed to reduce the file I had originally by about 60% and took around 120 seconds to run.

Version 2 with HashSet

```
$timer = Measure-Command {
    $inputPath  = 'C:\test\test.xml'
    $outputPath = 'C:\test\test99.xml'

    $fullInputPath = Convert-Path -LiteralPath $inputPath
    $fullOutputPath = (New-Item $outputPath -ItemType File -Force).FullName

    $reader = $writer = $null

    # Define an array of node names to skip
    $skipNodes = @(
        'g:condition',
        'g:material',
        'g:age_group',
        'g:gender',
        'g:pattern',
        'g:mpn',
        'g:shipping',
        'g:custom_label_0',
        'g:custom_label_1',
        'g:custom_label_2',
        'g:custom_label_3',
        'g:custom_label_4',
        'g:custom_label_5',
        'g:country',
        'g:service',
        'g:promotion_id',
        'g:product_highlight',
        'c:shopping_spend',
        'c:fs_data_opti',
        'c:fs_date_of_birth',
        'c:fs_data_original_id',
        'c:fs_data_original_title',
        'c:sales_feature',
        'c:stock',
        'c:google_product_name',
        'c:count',
        'c:order_number'
    )

    # HashSet is faster for lookup.
    $skipNodesHash = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]] $skipNodes

    try {
        # Create an XmlReader for the input file
        $reader = [Xml.XmlReader]::Create( $fullInputPath )

        # Create an XmlWriter for the output file
        $writer = [Xml.XmlWriter]::Create( $fullOutputPath )

        # Read first node (XML declaration)
        $null = $reader.Read()

        while( -not $reader.EOF ) {

            if( $reader.NodeType -eq [Xml.XmlNodeType]::Element ) {

                # Should the current element be removed from the output?
                if ($reader.Depth -eq 3 -and $skipNodesHash.Contains($reader.Name)) {
                    $reader.Skip()

                    # Read the next line to check if it's blank
                    $nextLine = $reader.ReadOuterXml()

                    # If the next line is blank, replace it with an empty string
                    if ($nextLine -match '^\s*$') {
                        $output = $output -replace "$nextLine", ''
                    }

                    continue
                }

                $writer.WriteStartElement( $reader.Prefix, $reader.LocalName, $reader.NamespaceUri )
                
                if( $reader.HasAttributes ) {
                    # Copy attributes
                    while( $reader.MoveToNextAttribute() ) {
                        $writer.WriteStartAttribute( $reader.Prefix, $reader.LocalName, $reader.NamespaceUri )
                        $writer.WriteString( $reader.Value )
                        $writer.WriteEndAttribute()
                    }                
                }

                # Read next node
                $null = $reader.Read()
            }
            else {
                # Copy any non-element node. Advances reader position as well!
                $writer.WriteNode( $reader, $false )
            }
        }    
    }
    finally {
        # Cleanup
        $reader, $writer | ForEach-Object Dispose
    }
}

"Elapsed time: $($timer.TotalSeconds) seconds"
```

Comment: Great that my answer enabled you to build a solution on your own. Just one thing to try for performance improvement: Move the definition of `$skipNodes` before the loop and make it a [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-7.0) for faster lookup: `$skipNodes = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]] @('g:condition', 'g:material', …)`.